# Simple Linq to List(of T)

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I trying to do what seems to be a simple thing but I'm having problems. The answers I find aren't working. I'm still getting casting exceptions:

```
Dim query = (From l In dePhl.cv_phil Where l.batch = strMmddyyyy
Select l.zipfile.Distinct)
Dim objFileList As List(Of String) = query.ToList() 'Error
```

Error:

> Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of Char))' cannot be converted to 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)'

It seems to work for other people! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the type of `l.zipfile`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want a distinct list of `String` values.  If that's the case then your use of use of `Distinct` is incorrect because your picking distinct `Char` values from every `String`.  Try the following

```
Dim query = (From l In dePhl.cv_phil Where l.batch = strMmddyyyy
Select l.zipfile)
Dim objFileList As List(Of String) = query.Distinct().ToList()
```